# Conditionally embedding records in an ember-data model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have embedded records using a model serializer.

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    myRelationships: {
      serialize: 'records'
    },
  }
});
```

The problem is that there are times I don't want to serialize the relationships.  How can I do this?

Comment: At what times do you want to, or not want to, serialize the relationships?

Comment: When I do `model.save()` I don't want embedded records.  When I do `model.execute(model.serialize())` I do want embedded records.  I have creted an execute command via the [ember-api-actions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-api-actions) addon.  I need this because the user wan't to be able to run a report based on the current state without actually saving the model.